# Wordpress Ordering Problem. How to fix ordering 1-10-100 issue?

Tags: categories, order

I have categories the names of which are 1 to 25. But the WordPress ordering system doesn't work correctly. It orders them as 1,10,11,12,13...2,21,22,23,24,25. I don't want to add 0 to 1-9 numbers. How can I fix this issue?

This is my code:

```
<li class="categoriesx <?php echo print_category_slug( get_the_category( $post->ID) ); ?>" 
    data-category="<?php echo print_category_slug( get_the_category( $post->ID) ); ?>">
```

Comment: please, show your code

Comment: I use this code for my theme : 

<li class="categoriesx  <?php echo print_category_slug( get_the_category( $post->ID) ); ?>" data-category="<?php echo print_category_slug( get_the_category( $post->ID) ); ?>">

Comment: If you click the [**edit** button](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/247680/edit) under your question, you can make changes to the original question. Code posted in comments is generally unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the research I've done on this, using term meta data is a better all around approach to ordering terms.

However, I was able come up with this snippet which does sort the terms by their name, numerically:

```
add_filter( 'terms_clauses', 'wpse247680_terms_clauses', 10, 3 );
function wpse247680_terms_clauses( $pieces, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    // Bail if we are not looking at the right taxonomy, 'category' in this case.
    if ( ! in_array( 'category', $taxonomies ) ) {
        return $pieces;
    }

    // Casts the term name to an integer
    // Idea derrived from similar idea using posts here: https://www.fldtrace.com/custom-post-types-numeric-title-order
    $pieces['orderby'] = 'ORDER BY (t.name+0) ';

    return $pieces;
}
```

Here's a screenshot showing this in action in the admin area. For testing, I created a new taxonomy named 'numeral', and created the terms in an arbitrary order. When the code posted above is used, the terms will be ordered numerically.
[image: sort terms numerically by name]

Comment: Thanks you very much! It worked :) Do you know how to fix same problem with showing the posts? It has same problem with posts.

Comment: Glad that worked out, Yearmaz. Would you please post a new question for sorting posts please?

Comment: Okey I posted new question. Please look : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247871/wordpress-ordering-problem-how-to-fix-ordering-1-10-100-issue-for-posts

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will order your categories alphabetically, which leads to the result you get. You want to order them numerically. PHP can do this for you. Let's say you have an array of categories, ordered randomly, like this:

```
$cats = array ('3', '22', '17', ... '7');
```

You can then use [PHP sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) while forcing a numerical sorting order:

```
sort ($cats, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

That should give you

```
$cats = array ('1', '2', '3', ... '25');
```

Comment: Sorry for that but I am not proffesional to code. Where do I need to edit or where do I need to add this code to?

Comment: I believe [`get_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) can orderby IDs if need be.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Yes, but these are not ID's but names

Comment: @Yearmaz You put it in the place where you need it. I don't know where that place is or why you want this order anyway.

Comment: I added the code to functions.php but nothing happened. :(