# Problem ordering posts with numbers for titles numerically E.g. 1, 10, 100

Tags: posts, order

I have posts that are named from 1 to 25. But, the WordPress ordering system doesn't work correctly. It orders them as 1,10,11,12,13...2,21,22,23,24,25. I don't want to add 0 to 1-9 numbers. How can I fix this issue?

I opened same question for categories but I have same problem with posts. My previous question is [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247680/wordpress-ordering-problem-how-to-fix-ordering-1-10-100-issue).

How can I fix same problem for ordering the posts?

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that will order posts by the `post_title` field, numerically. This code will affect the main query for posts on both the back end and front end.

```
// Apply numeric post ordering for posts in admin and front end.
// Adapted from https://www.fldtrace.com/custom-post-types-numeric-title-order
function wpse247871_post_order( $wp_query ) {
    if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->query['post_type'] == 'post' ) { 
        add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse247871_orderby_post_title_int' );
    }  
}  
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'wpse247871_post_order');

// Cast the post_title field as an integer in SQL.
function wpse247871_orderby_post_title_int( $orderby ) {
    global $wpdb;
    return "({$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_title+0) ASC";
}
```

Comment: It's 2023 and now we do `'orderby' => 'title_num',`